# AWS CloudWatch Event isn't triggering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I tried creating a cloudwatch event rule with the below code. However, it doesn't seem to be working. I checked AWS CloudWatch Events, and the rule is there with my attached lambda function. However, the event never gets triggered as it should. How can I fix this problem?

```
async function createCloudWatchEvent(zip){
    if(zip){
        try{
            await putRule(zip);
            await putTarget(zip);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Can't create [${zip}] cloudwatch event`);
        }
    }
}

function putRule (ruleName) {
    let cloudWatchParams = {
      Name: ruleName, // required
      ScheduleExpression: 'rate(1 minute)',
      State: 'ENABLED'
    };

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        cloudwatchevent.putRule(cloudWatchParams, async function(err, data) {
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
            resolve(err);
          }else{
            console.log('Successfully created rule: ' + ruleName);
            resolve();
          }
        });
    });
}

function putTarget (ruleName) {
    let cloudWatchParams = {
      Rule: ruleName, // required
      Targets: [ // required
        {
          Arn: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
          Id: 'Determine_State',
          Input: JSON.stringify({zip: ruleName})
        }
      ]
    };

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // Attach "Determine_State" target to cloudwatch event
        cloudwatchevent.putTargets(cloudWatchParams, function(err, data) {
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
            resolve(err);
          }else{
            console.log('Successfully attached target [' + cloudWatchParams.Targets[0].Id + '] to rule: ' + ruleName);
            resolve();
          }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you know t already, the cron schedule that you set to your lambda functions are in UTC time. For e.g, if you specify 5 pm, it is 5 pm UTC time. Maybe you are checking the logs before it executes.

#### Lambda permissions to log to cloudwatch

the lambda should have permission to log to cloudwatch. otherwise the lambda function will not add logs to cloudwatch. here is a policy that you can refer.

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                 "logs:CreateLogStream",
                 "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Reference:

[Can't get AWS Lambda function to log (text output) to CloudWatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382889/cant-get-aws-lambda-function-to-log-text-output-to-cloudwatch)

hope this helps.

Comment: I commented out the cron expression and changed it to 'rate(1 minute)' for testing.

Comment: does your lambda got permission to push logs to cloudwatch

Comment: I just did a test and works for me with the policy above.

Comment: Once I add the permissions to my lambda's execution role, I had to redeploy the lambda for the log group to be created. good luck

Comment: I added this policy to lambda execution role. How do I redeploy the lambda to create the log group?{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: you can get your ci/cd to do it, for testing I have deployed from lambda console (Actions => publish new version)

Comment: It still doesn't work. I even tried creating a new lambda function, but it didn't make a difference. I do see the log group though.

Comment: Can you edit the cloudwatch event to see whether it shows you the next 10 occurrences of the schedule

Comment: When I manually create the event by hand, the event rule works. However, the code doesn't work. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: The event also only works once I manually update the event after it's been created by the code.

Comment: sorry I dont have an answer. I suggest you raise an AWS support ticket

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to give permission to invoke your lambda function from the CloudWatch events (your rule). Have a look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) tutorial.

You have to either do it via CLI or from the language's AWS API. Eg:

```
aws lambda add-permission \
--function-name LogScheduledEvent \
--statement-id my-scheduled-event \
--action 'lambda:InvokeFunction' \
--principal events.amazonaws.com \
--source-arn arn:aws:events:us-east-1:123456789012:rule/my-scheduled-rule
```