# AWS Lambda function not being triggered at all

Tags: aws-lambda

I am trying to create a simple lambda function that is triggered when a bucket is uploaded with a file. My lambda function have 2 policies as of now - a cloudwatch policy to log and an s3 bucket get object policy listed as below

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        }

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the default example-bucket test to verify if the lambda function works as per the setup.
[image]
I've changed the basic hello text print to something different. I see that this has no effect and event my print bucket is not working. I've went through this other post on SO [lambda cloudwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382889/cant-get-aws-lambda-function-to-log-text-output-to-cloudwatch) and verified the similier steps. I am creating my function after creating my policy. Any inputs as to why my function is not being triggered ?

Comment: Have you clicked `deploy`?

Comment: Ok did that my friend and now it works !! Crap, I was racking my head for an hour to know the issue. I thought deploy is more like productionalizing the code.

Comment: I'm glad it works. Please consider accepting my answer below. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment, the solution is to click `deploy` :)